# Why Android Retrofit works different than IOS Alamofire?

Tags: android, ios, retrofit2, okhttp

I have implemented a mobile application in IOS and Android using TCP socket connections to a common server. As the title says, in Android I use Retrofit2 with okhttp-3.2.0, in IOS I use AlamoFire.

Whenever internet connectivity is non-reliable I am getting many more connection timeouts in Android than in IOS, even if I manually set both to have 30s timeout.
My theory is that IOS/Alamofire implements some default TCP parameters that are more resilient to bad connections.

Is it possible to print/modify the TCP low level parameters in Retrofit2/okhttp? and Alamofile?